Error when running permission_handler on iOS Device in flutter
I am using permission_handler to request permission for local notifications in a flutter app. However when I run the app on an iOS device it crashes.
I added permission_handler: ^11.3.1 in pubspec.yaml. Is that enough?
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future<void> requestNotificationPermission() async {
  if (await Permission.notification.isDenied) {
    await Permission.notification.request();
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await requestNotificationPermission(); // Request permission on app launch

  runApp(MyApp());
}


I have this error when running on ios device:
    [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:     MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel     flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      MethodChannelPermissionHandler.checkPermissionStatus  (package:permission_handler_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_permission_handler .dart:17:20)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      requestNotificationPermission (package:bmicalculator/main.dart:11:16)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      main (package:bmicalculator/main.dart:21:3)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

Tried running flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter run. Added UIBackgroundModes and NSUserNotificationUsageDescription to Info.plist.
Changed the pubspec.yaml by adding permission_handler.
Can anyone please help?

can you provide the code where you implemented permission_handler?

Sure: import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
Future requestNotificationPermission() async {
if (await Permission.notification.isDenied) {
await Permission.notification.request();
}
}
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await requestNotificationPermission(); // Request permission on app launch
runApp(MyApp());
}

pub upgrade 
flutter clean, flutter pub get
cd IOS, pod install after 

